# Which Backdrop themes allow viewing CiviCRM inline fields without scrolling?

Tags: theme, usability, backdrop, ux

By default, CiviCRM on Drupal's "Bartik" theme and Backdrop's "Basis" and "Seven" themes cause CiviCRM inline fields to display with horizontal scroll bars, which hurts usability (see screenshot 1).

In Drupal, the [civi_bartik](https://www.drupal.org/project/civi_bartik) theme fixes this (see screenshot 2).  Is there an equivalent theme for Backdrop CMS?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does `civi_bartik` just force the wrapper/container to be wider or is it doing something else? I just did a quick test in Seven and changing `.container` to have a max-width of 1250px appears to be enough (if your screen is big enough). This doesn't help on smaller screens of course.

Comment: Has this been improved in CiviCRM core in recent years? Seems to be better out of the box.

Comment: @Laryn-CEDC.org Yes, there's been a JS fix to handle this.  I'm wondering if it makes sense to delete this question?  There's no supported version of Civi where this would be an issue.

Comment: Maybe so in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding nothing better, I made my own Seven subtheme [civi_seven](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/civi_seven).

CSS is definitely not my strong suit, but the net result is definitely an improvement on the existing options.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen one. Usually in cases like this I just make changes to the theme myself to account for things like this. Themes often times only take Drupal, its core modules, and some of the major add-ons into consideration for its theme. So when you use something else, like CiviCRM, you have to make changes yourself for usability.